# Last.FM scrobble via post.audioscrobbler.com

Tags: last.fm

I am trying to create a simple app that scrobbles songs. If I follow these instructions (http://www.lastfm.de/api/submissions) the handshake responds with OK and I get a session ID as well as the submission URLs. But when I try to scrobble a song the response is:

Audioscrobbler submissions system.
http://www.audioscrobbler.net/

and nothing is scrobbled. Has the service been discontinued or why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scrobble submissions must be sent with the HTTP POST method.

The service has not (and will not) be discontinued as there is a large number of legacy applications still using it. But we prefer the newer Scrobble 2.0 protocol to be used when possible: http://www.last.fm/api/scrobbling